# How can I transform this dataset in pandas so that it easy to filter and compare?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
Segments    Airline_pct_tesco   Airline_pct_asda    food_pct_tesco  food_pct_asda   Airline_diff    food_diff
        A   1                       2                   4               2               -1              2
        B   2                       2                   4               4               0               0
        c   10                      5                   12              10              5               2
```

I want to convert it to this format:

```
Segments    Category    Asda%   Tesco%  Diff%
A           Airline     2       1       -1
b           Food        4       4       0
c           Airline     5       10      5
A           Food        2       4       2
```

(only partially showing). Note
category is the col name without the '_pct_tesco' or '_diff' or '_pct_asda'

I am unsure how to go about this - I have tried transform but I just don't know how I can get it in a way which is easy for any user to use. I am doing this in pandas and am not sure how to even begin! The Asda% are related to '_pct_asda' columns and same for diff and tesco columns respectively..

Comment: Please can you update your post with text data instead of image?

Comment: how will this help you? I am not sure how to put it into text

Comment: yes  i have just done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to save columns, then create a [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html) using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) on the columns to create a MultiIndex based on the values before a list of suffixes, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to go to long-form.

```
new_df = df.set_index('Segments')
# Define allowed suffixes here
suffixes = ['_pct_asda', '_pct_tesco', '_diff']
# Extract Values
new_df.columns = (
    pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
        new_df.columns.str.extract(rf'(.*?)({"|".join(suffixes)})'),
        names=['Category', None]
    )
)
new_df = new_df.stack(0)
```

`new_df`:

```
                   _diff  _pct_asda  _pct_tesco
Segments Category                              
A        Airline      -1          2           1
         food          2          2           4
B        Airline       0          2           2
         food          0          4           4
c        Airline       5          5          10
         food          2         10          12
```

---

To get cleaner output add [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to fix column names and index and also re-order columns.

```
new_df = new_df.reset_index().rename(columns={
    '_pct_asda': 'Asda%',
    '_pct_tesco': 'Tesco%',
    '_diff': 'Diff%'
})[['Segments', 'Category', 'Asda%', 'Tesco%', 'Diff%']]
```

`new_df`:

```
  Segments Category  Asda%  Tesco%  Diff%
0        A  Airline      2       1     -1
1        A     food      2       4      2
2        B  Airline      2       2      0
3        B     food      4       4      0
4        c  Airline      5      10      5
5        c     food     10      12      2
```

Comment: The use of str.split to produce MultiIndex is very smart!

Comment: thanks for this.. i forgot to add that te coluomn names can sometimes be more complex e.g.:  like: beauty_101_pct_tesco or beauty_101_pct_asda... basically the catgeoriy can take form before the '_pct_asda' and so the above fails for these cases

Comment: Easy fix, just extract instead of split. Try now.

Comment: for some reason it is not picking up any colyumns with numbers in e.g. gb_store_115_pct_diff <-- this doesn't come up

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue. It processes number columns fine on my end, however, I do notice that that is '_pct_diff' not '_diff' which would cause a duplicate entry.